# Capacitor decade box

Tags: capacitor, test, ideal

I'm assembling a capacitor decade box. It will be used to tune circuits both in power & high frequency electronics (but, probably not GHz RF; with all the parasitics).

So, I need it to be as low tolerance as possible (high accuracy), whilst having low esr (for ideal behavior), low leakage (for DC), works at high frequencies (for AC), high tolerance to ripple current (so to not be aged too quickly) & lastly, a long lifespan (that the the characteristics do not change too appreciably given years & years).

Maybe also a capacitor type that does not have polarity or not too sensitive to over/reverse voltage would be good as well.

Anybody knows the best capacitor that fits this unicorn ideal capacitor description?

Comment: Film capacitors, probably. Hand-selected to get tighter binning than the tolerance rating suggests.

Comment: (For small signals and frequencies, you may be able to get by using a capacitance multiplier.)

Comment: Polypropylene film and foil capacitors is my choice.

Comment: would be important to actually spell out 1. capacitance range you want to cover, 2. frequency range, 3. amplitude range, 4. DC offset range, if any.

Comment: How long leads will you have into your capacitor decade box? The inductance of the leads would certainly make any capacitance useless for high frequencies.

Comment: @Müller: 1.) single digit pF - mF range; 2.) single digit GHz; 3.) 110V; 4.) DC offset for capacitors? I don't know what that is. Is that an effect by leakage? Yeah, very demanding.

Comment: @Justme: Yeah, I've never had to factor stray inductance in the past, so I almost forgot about this. Would using Litz wire that is not woven together (just parallel) work? Like assembling everything in a perforated board, but instead of the etched traces, I'll have Litz wire? Or would that only take care of the skin effect? And, actually increase inductance?

Comment: @greybeard: Capacitance multiplier? Maybe that could be useful to me in the future. Right now, I aim for robustness.

Comment: `@Müller: 1.) single digit pF - mF range; 2.) single digit GHz; 3.) 110V;` edit information inviting useful answers into the question body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For pF up to about 100nF and 50V or 100V (1uF if you are willing to put some in parallel or pay through the nose), NP0/COG ceramic capacitors.

For (somewhat) higher capacitances, stacked film such as PPS (Polyphenylene Sulfide) is pretty good in terms of tempco and dissipation constant.

Answer (score 2):

Stack ceramic caps in parallel, it will lower ESR since resistors in parallel get very small and caps increase in parallel, same as ESL (eevblog, why do we stack caps).
I also recomend capacitance multiplier circuit explained on eevblog, you could work from there and play with gain for diffrent capacitance, but I don't know the complications that comes with such circuit for your applications.

Comment: Good idea but will it help if there is e.g. 10 cm of ESL from wiring and selector switch?

Comment: hm, ceramic caps have nonlinearity. This *can* be corrected out if this is used for e.g. single-tone tests (low-pass filter out harmonics caused by the nonlinearity, apply correction curve for derated "linear" capacitance), but depending on the amplitude range of the signals, this can be a dealbreaker for a measurement standard.

Comment: @Justme what for ? the ESL will get lowered as well, BTW I got this idea from eevblog why do we stack caps in parallel episode

Comment: @AhmedH2O The added ESR and ESL from wires between caps and device will surely nullify or negate the effect of putting caps in parallel at the end of wires.